# Why can you have an pointer to array of strings in C

Tags: c, pointers

why does

```
char *names [] = {"hello", "Jordan"};
```

work fine

but this does not

```
char names [] = {"hello", "Jordan"};
```

would appreciate if someone could explain this to me, thank you :).

Comment: First one is an array of pointers to strings. The second one is an array of `chars`. I guess this should be enough to explain why the first one is OK and the second one is not...

Comment: Because `char[]` is an array of characters, not an array of strings. It's the same reason `char *foo = "Hi";` works, but `char foo = "Hi";` does not (though the first one really should be `const char *`).

Comment: Why do you expect the `*` does not make a difference? What is unclear about the `*` in a declaration, what does your textbook omit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
char *names [] = {"hello", "Jordan"};
```

`names` is **array of char pointers** i.e it can holds pointers i.e `names` each elements itself is one char array. But here

```
char names [] = {"hello", "Jordan"};
```

`names` is just a *char array* i.e it can hold only single char array like `"hello"` not multiple.

In second case like

```
int main(void) {
        char names[] = {"hello", "Jordan"};
        return 0;
}
```

when you compile(Suggest you to compile with `-Wall -pedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror` flags), compiler clearly says

> error: excess elements in char array initializer

which means you can't have more than one char array in this case. Correct one is

```
char names[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}; /* here names is array of characters */
```

**Edit :-** Also there is more possibility if syntax of `names` looks like below

```
char names[] = { "hello" "Jordan" }; /* its a valid one */
```

then here both `hello` and `Jordan` gets joined & it becomes single char array `helloJordan`.

```
char names[] = { "helloJordan" };
```

Answer (score 2):

The first is an array of pointers to char.  The second is an array of char and would have to look like `char names[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}`

Comment: ...or `char names[] = "abc"` - with an implicit `\0` as fourth element.

Answer (score 0):

`char name[]` is an array of characters so you can store a word in it:

```
char name[] = "Muzol";
```

This is the same of:

```
char name[] = {'M', 'u', 'z', 'o', 'l', '\0'}; /* '\0' is NULL, it means end of the array */
```

And `char* names[]` is an array of arrays where each element of the first array points to the start of the elements of the second array.

```
char* name[] = {"name1", "name2"};
```

It's the same of:

```
char name1[] = {'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '1', '\0'}; /* or char name1[] = "name1"; */
char name2[] = {'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '2', '\0'}; /* or char name2[] = "name2"; */
char* names[] = { name1, name2 };
```

So basically `names[0]` points to `&name1[0]`, where it can read the memory until `name1[5]`, this is where it finds the `'\0' (NULL)` character and stops. The same happens for `name2[]`;

Answer (score 0):

A string literal, such as `"hello"`, is stored in static memory as an array of `char`s. In fact, a string literal has type `char [N]`, where `N` is the number of characters in the array (including the `\0` terminator). In most cases, an array identifier decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, so in most expressions a string literal such as `"hello"` will decay to a pointer to the `char` element `'h'`.

```
char *names[] = { "hello", "Jordan" };
```

Here the two string literals decay to pointers to `char` which point to `'h'` and `'J'`, respectively. That is, here the string literals have type `char *` after the conversion. These types agree with the declaration on the left, and the array `names[]` (which is not an array of character type, but an array of `char *`) is initialized using these two pointer values.

```
char names[] = "hello";
```

or similarly:

```
char names[] = { "hello" };
```

Here we encounter a special case. Array identifiers are *not* converted to pointers to their first elements when they are operands of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, *or when they are string literals used to initialize an array of character type*. So in this case, the string literal `"hello"` does not decay to a pointer; instead the characters contained in the string literal are used to initialize the array `names[]`.

```
char names[] = {"hello", "Jordan"};
```

Again, the string literals would be used to initialize the array `names[]`, but there are *excess initializers* in the initializer list. This is a *constraint violation* according to the Standard. From §[6.7.9 ¶2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p2) of the C11 Draft Standard:

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

A conforming implementation must issue a diagnostic in the event of a constraint violation, which may take the form of a warning or an error. On the version of gcc that I am using at the moment (gcc 6.3.0) this diagnostic is an error:

```
error: excess elements in char array initializer
```

Yet, for arrays of `char` that are initialized by an initializer list of `char` values rather than by string literals, the same diagnostic is a warning instead of an error.

In order to initialize an array of `char` that is not an array of pointers, you would need a 2d array of `char`s here. Note that the second dimension is required, and must be large enough to contain the largest string in the initializer list:

```
char names[][100] = { "hello", "Jordan" };
```

Here, each string literal is used to initialize an array of 100 `char`s contained within the larger 2d array of `char`s. Or, put another way, `names[][]` is an array of arrays of 100 `char`s, each of which is initialized by a string literal from the initializer list.